# How to disable related content from showing on my posts

Tags: hugo, blogdown

Hugo and blogdown newbie. I'm using the [minimal theme](https://github.com/calintat/minimal) which automatically suggests related content within my posts. For example

[image: related posts]

I would like to disable this feature. The Hugo docs have a section on [related content](https://gohugo.io/content-management/related/#configure-related-content) but I don't see specific instructions on *turning off* related content. I've tried setting `related = false` in *config.toml* but to no avail.

Steps to reproduce:

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = "calintat/minimal")
blogdown::serve_site()
```

Now navigate to *Posts > Creating a New Theme* and scroll to the bottom to see the "Related" section.

UPDATE:

I got this working by modifying the line `{{ $related := first 3 ...` to `{{ $related := first 0 ...` inside *themes/minimal/layouts/_default/single.html* but I have to believe there's a cleaner way to do this, where my change won't get overwritten the next time I update my theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to make modifications to a theme is to take advantage of the "look-up" order in Hugo, in order to "override" the theme file with a local one.

For example, to override `themes/minimal/layouts/_default/single.html`, you can copy it to `layouts/_default/single.html` and modify it without worrying about losing changes.

Read more from the [hugo manual](https://gohugo.io/templates/base/#override-the-base-template).